# Integrate $\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{dx}{1 + x^n}$ using the Residue Theorem

Tags: complex-analysis, contour-integration, residue-calculus

I'm trying to compute the following integral:

> \begin{align}
> \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{dx}{1 + x^n}, \quad n \geq 2.
> \end{align}

Consider the function $f(z) = \frac{1}{1 + z^n}$. Consider the following contour, $\Gamma_n$:

[image]

We then have,

\begin{align}
\int_{\Gamma_n} = \int_{0}^{R} \frac{dz}{1 + z^n} + \int_{\Gamma_n^{1}} \frac{dz}{1 + z^n} + \int_{\Gamma_n^{2}} \frac{dz}{1 + z^n},
\end{align}

where $\Gamma_n^{1}$ denotes an arc of the circle, $R e^{i \theta}, \theta \in [0, 2\pi] $. I have shown that the integral along this arc goes to zero as $R$ goes to $\infty$. I'm having trouble with the integral along the arc $\Gamma_n^{2}$. Here's what I have done:

Parametrize $\Gamma_n^{2}$ as,

\begin{align}
z(t) = \Big (1 - \frac{t}{R} \Big ) R e^{\frac{2 \pi i}{n}}, \quad t \in [0, R].
\end{align}

We then have,

\begin{align}
dz(t) & = - e^{\frac{2 \pi i}{n}} dt, \\
1 + z(t)^n & = 1 + R^n \Big (1 - \frac{t}{R} \Big )^n = 1 + R^n \sum_{k = 0}^{n} (-1)^k \Big ( \frac{t}{R} \Big )^k \\ 
& = 1 + R^n - t R^{n-1} + t^2 R^{n-2} - \cdots + (-1)^n t^n.
\end{align}

Hence, we have that,

\begin{align}
\int_{\Gamma_n^{2}} \frac{dz}{1 + z^n} = - e^{\frac{2 \pi i}{n}} \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{dt}{1 + R^n - t R^{n-1} + t^2 R^{n-2} - \cdots + (-1)^n t^n}.
\end{align}

I'm not sure how to proceed from here. The answer given states that this integral converges to,

\begin{align}
- e^{\frac{2 \pi i}{n}} \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{dx}{1 + x^n}.
\end{align}

Comment: Is $\Gamma_n^2$ the straight line from $0$ to $R\exp(2\pi i/n)$? Then that's a jolly peculiar way of parametrising it. How about $t\exp(2\pi i/n)$?

Comment: Maybe it will be easier to use the parametrization $z(t) = Re^{2\pi i/n} t$, with $t\in [0,1]$, and then invert the boundaries of integration.

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown I'll try that.

Comment: @giobrach Initially, I used this parameterization, but I wasn't sure how I'll I get the limits from $0$ to $\infty$ in this case. I thought both the limits and the integrand must depend on $R$.

Comment: @user82261 Actually, when you’re trying to prove that an integral on one of the contour components goes to zero, things usually work out much nicer when the limits are fixed.

Comment: @giobrach True, but the claim is that the integral along the tilted straight line does not go to zero, which is something I checked online. So I think I need to incorporate $R$ in the parameterization, but perhaps choose a different parameterization.

Comment: @user82261 Ah, it was not clear what you meant in the question.

Comment: @giobrach Sorry about that. I did, however, include at the end that the integral converges to the integral given at the end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that $\Gamma_n^1$ is an arc of a circle, not a semicircle (in general).

Besides,\begin{align}\int_{\Gamma_n^2}\frac{\mathrm dz}{1+z^n}&=\int_0^R\frac{-e^{\frac{2\pi i}n}}{1+\left(1-\frac tR\right)^nR^n}\,\mathrm dt\\&=-e^{\frac{2\pi i}n}\int_0^R\frac{\mathrm dt}{1+(R-t)^n}\\&=-e^{\frac{2\pi i}n}\int_0^R\frac{\mathrm dt}{1+t^n}\\&=-e^{\frac{2\pi i}n}\int_0^R\frac{\mathrm dz}{1+z^n}.\end{align}Can you take it from here?

Comment: Oh, I overlooked that a change of variable would do the trick here. Yes, I can. Thanks.